# How to add an index of a another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two different dataframes. First I had to check that the data in my df1 matches my df2.  If that were the case, it add a column "isRep" = true otherwise it's equal to false. It created a df3 for me.

Now, I need to add an "idRep" column in my df3 that corresponds to the index, generate automatically with pandas, where to find the data in df2

This is the df1 :

```
Index      Firstname      Name       Origine
  0        Johnny         Depp       USA
  1        Brad           Pitt       USA
  2        Angelina       Pitt       USA
```

This is the d2 :

```
Index      Firstname      Name       Origine
  0        Kidman         Nicole     AUS
  1        Jean           Dujardin   FR
  2        Brad           Pitt       USA
```

After the merge with this code :

```
df = pd.merge(data, dataRep, on=['Firstname', 'Name', 'Origine'], how='left', indicator='IsRep')
df['IsRep'] = np.where(df.IsRep == 'both', True, False)
```

after this code, I got this result which is my df3 (its the same of the df1 but with the column "isRep" ) :

```
Index      Firstname      Name       Origine   isRep
  0        Johnny         Depp       USA       False
  1        Brad           Pitt       USA       True
  2        Angelina       Pitt       USA       False
```

Now, I need an other dataframe with the column named "idRep" where I put the index corresponds to df2 like that. But I don't know how I can do that:

```
Index      Firstname      Name       Origine   isRep    IdRep
  0        Johnny         Depp       USA       False    -
  1        Brad           Pitt       USA       True     2
  2        Angelina       Pitt       USA       False    -
```

Comment: and what is the question/desired output?

Comment: I need to have a new dataframe with the column "IdRep" like the last example in my explication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack would be to **`reset_index`** before you merge.  Only reset the index on the right DataFrame.

---

```
m = dataRep.rename_axis('IdRep').reset_index()

df = pd.merge(data, m, on=['Firstname', 'Name', 'Origine'], how='left', indicator='IsRep')
df['IsRep'] = np.where(df.IsRep == 'both', True, False)
```

```
  Firstname  Name Origine  IdRep  IsRep
0    Johnny  Depp     USA    NaN  False
1      Brad  Pitt     USA    2.0   True
2  Angelina  Pitt     USA    NaN  False
```

Comment: This is so simple.  I love it.

Answer (score 1):

#### reverse look up using `dict`

```
cols = ['Firstname', 'Name', 'Origine']
d = dict(zip(zip(*map(df2.get, cols)), df2.index))
z = [*zip(*map(df1.get, cols))]

df1.assign(
    isRep=[*map(d.__contains__, z)],
    IdRep=[*map(d.get, z)]
)

      Firstname  Name Origine  isRep  IdRep
Index                                      
0        Johnny  Depp     USA  False    NaN
1          Brad  Pitt     USA   True    2.0
2      Angelina  Pitt     USA  False    NaN
```

---

Variation where we take advantage of `assign` arguments being order dependent

```
cols = ['Firstname', 'Name', 'Origine']
d = dict(zip(zip(*map(df2.get, cols)), df2.index))
z = [*zip(*map(df1.get, cols))]

df1.assign(
    IdRep=[*map(d.get, z)],
    isRep=lambda d: d.IdRep.notna()
)
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Please treat this answer as an exploratory exercise.  You chose correctly with @user3483203's answer (-: